# Entity Framework 7 keeps creating the same migration, and isn't picking up any model changes

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My EF7 command of: `dnx ef migrations add NAME_HERE` is constantly creating the same exact migration every time I run it. Even if I update the database with `dnx ef database update`, and watch the changes pushed to the DB, I'll add a new migration and it creates the same thing again.

Also note, the migration isn't picking up my model changes. Properties that I've removed from my model are not showing up in the migration.

The code that it keeps generating over and over is:

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_FooEvent_Organizer_OrganizerForeignKey", table: "FooEvent");
        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_FooEvent_Organizer_OrganizerForeignKey",
            table: "FooEvent",
            column: "OrganizerForeignKey",
            principalTable: "Organizer",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_FooEvent_Organizer_OrganizerForeignKey", table: "FooEvent");
        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_FooEvent_Organizer_OrganizerForeignKey",
            table: "FooEvent",
            column: "OrganizerForeignKey",
            principalTable: "Organizer",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    }
}
```

My DbContext looks like this:

```
public DbSet<FaroEvent> FaroEvents { get; set; }
public DbSet<Organizer> Organizers { get; set; }
```

And my model's related properties to the migration are:

```
public int OrganizerForeignKey { get; set; }

[Required, ForeignKey("OrganizerForeignKey")]
public Organizer Organizer { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foreign key issue is fixed in rc2: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3751

If the migration isn't picking up model changes I would suggest you look in your Migrations[context_name]ContextModelSnapshot.cs file to see what EF thinks your model is. You can attempt a manual repair of the snapshot file or delete the ContextModelSnapshot.cs file and all your migrations and start again with an initial migration.